# Why tree view not rendered in div is it DOM element positioning error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree, treeview

I am trying to render a tree with certain childs in a div using javascript and html. I am wondering why it is not rendering given all  the objects are created and everything is fine in read of tree and parent 
from Json (see "data" in my code).

NOTE:I have Layout.cshtml and it shares the top most menu which is "Application Name" at the top and is like this http://prntscr.com/7czhas

Could some one please let me know why tree don't appear in my div with ID:`jqxTree`

My code is 2nd edit:
I am trying to render a tree with certain childs in a div using javascript and html. I am wondering why it is not rendering given all  the objects are created and everything is fine in read of tree and parent 
from Json (see "data" in my code).

Could some one please let me know why tree don't appear in my div with ID:`jqxTree`

My code is 2nd edit:

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "TreeCreation";
}

<h2>TreeCreation</h2>



<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/bootstrap/js/LiveMap/Ajax/JsonStringCarryingData/jqx-all.js"></script>
    <link href="~/bootstrap/css/LiveMap/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/bootstrap/css/LiveMap/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id='jqxTree' style="background-color:green; height:400px;width:200px;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
   {
       "text": "Chocolate Beverage",
       "id": "1",
       "parentid": "-1"
   }, {
       "id": "2",
       "parentid": "1",
       "text": "Hot Chocolate"
   }, {
       "id": "3",
       "parentid": "1",
       "text": "Peppermint Hot Chocolate"
   }, {
       "id": "4",
       "parentid": "1",
       "text": "Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate"
   }, {
       "id": "5",
       "parentid": "1",
       "text": "White Hot Chocolate"
   }, {
       "id": "6",
       "text": "Espresso Beverage",
       "parentid": "-1"
   }, {
       "id": "7",
       "parentid": "6",
       "text": "Caffe Americano"
   }, {
       "id": "8",
       "text": "Caffe Latte",
       "parentid": "6"
   }, {
       "id": "9",
       "text": "Caffe Mocha",
       "parentid": "6"
   }, {
       "id": "10",
       "text": "Cappuccino",
       "parentid": "6"
   }, {
       "id": "11",
       "text": "Pumpkin Spice Latte",
       "parentid": "6"
   }, {
       "id": "12",
       "text": "Frappuccino",
       "parentid": "-1"
   }, {
       "id": "13",
       "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino",
       "parentid": "12"
   }, {
       "id": "15",
       "text": "450 calories",
       "parentid": "13"
   }, {
       "id": "16",
       "text": "16g fat",
       "parentid": "13"
   }, {
       "id": "17",
       "text": "13g protein",
       "parentid": "13"
   }, {
       "id": "14",
       "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino Light",
       "parentid": "12"
   }]

        function run() {
            //  alert('Inside buidldata');
            var source = [];
            var items = [];
            // build hierarchical source.
            alert('data length:' + data.length);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var item = data[i];
                var label = item["text"];
                var parentid = item["parentid"];
                var id = item["id"];

                if (items[parentid]) {
                    var item = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
                    if (!items[parentid].items) {
                        items[parentid].items = [];
                    }
                    items[parentid].items[items[parentid].items.length] = item;
                    items[id] = item;
                }
                else {
                    items[id] = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
                    source[id] = items[id];
                }
            }
            return source;
        }
        // create jqxTree
        var source = run();
        alert('source:' + source);
        $('#jqxTree').jqxTree(
            {
                source: source, width: '350px'
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

**It also gives 2 errors http://prntscr.com/7czj92 and it makes me feel that there is some problem in this jqx-all.js file which i copy and pasted from the link http://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js . Please help me i am stuck here since last 4 days**

Comment: have you added the reference for jqxTree's js file?

Comment: @SherinMathew  No.. where to get that ?

Comment: You can find it **[here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/#demos/jqxtree/settings.htm)**

Comment: where to get that? Why did you decide to use jqxTree? I think @GuruprasadRao has posted the link.

Comment: @SherinMathew and @ Guruprasad Rao this link do not contain code for jqxTree.js so that o refer the link for  it in my code.

Comment: Please let us know the reason for calling  $('#jqxTree').jqxTree. From where did you get this code. The answer to this question will point you to the right direction. I.e to get the reference to jqxtree's js file.

Comment: jqxtree seems to be a licensed product. Please dowload the required scripts from http://www.jqwidgets.com/download/

Comment: a working sample of jqxtree is at http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/ccegq/. Please check the external references section on the left

Comment: I have update the above jsfiddle with your code and it works! http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/ccegq/274/

Comment: @SherinMathew I am folowing this link to provide a treeview http://www.jqwidgets.com/populating-jquery-tree-with-json-data/ and $('#jqxTree').jqxTree. i am doing because i want to render the tree view in a div which has ID jqxTree

Comment: @ajpr, did you check this link? it is working with your code. http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/ccegq/274/

Comment: Move your <div id='jqxTree' style="background-color:green;" > </div> just above the opening <script> tag. It is in the wrong place! i.e is should be between <body> and <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to the required js files.
i.e http://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js - Will contain the source for all jq widgets.

The files required are jqx-all.js, jqx.base.css and jqx.energyblue.css.
Add reference to the files as shown below.

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="jqx-all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='jqx.base.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='jqx.energyblue.css'>
```

Note : The above code is assuming that the required files are in the same folder as the current html.

If you are using only jqxtree, get the specific files from the vendor.

Please refer the working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/ccegq/274/
The external resources section on the left pane will show you the references required to run the code.

Comment: i have written all my code in EDIT part of question. I wonder why it still do not   show the tree thw output is like this http://prntscr.com/7cxvin (with those 2 popup alerts)

Comment: do you think it is because i am running it in View's cshtml obtained corresponding to controller ?  I am not able to find the reason for it's not owrking

Comment: Move your <div id='jqxTree' style="background-color:green;" >
</div> just above the opening <script> tag. It is in the wrong place! i.e is should be between <body> and <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: i am really tired of this problem ...really. I have done you aske done all you have asked me to do. But it still do not work. May i email you this project ? if you could please give me your email address . I am stuck on this problem since many days. (On emore thing this view is partial view of a Layout.cshmtl . Could that be a problem ?)

Comment: I dont think you should add the head section in the child html as the head section is present in the shared layout. This could be causing the issue. I can't confirm until i see the code.

Comment: i have just replied you in chat box please see

Comment: I found the solution . It need jquery-1.10.2.min.js not 10.1

Comment: Good! You should be happy now!

Comment: yes it is  working when in my Layout.cshtml i move <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> at the top from bottom but i still have .css not working i guess because it gives tree liek this http://prntscr.com/7czvan but it should give like this  http://prntscr.com/7czvlm that means it do not shows the arrows to be clicked

Comment: That is because you require the image files also from jqwidgets. I recommend downloading all required files from the vendor. The CSS will be referring to arrow images which will not be available in you localbox or server

Comment: you mean there is no other option rather thn purchasing in money all the files from vendor ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79656/discussion-between-sherin-mathew-and-ajpr).